# Problems with importCertificate function in electron

Tags: electron, pkcs#12, snapcraft

My electron app is running inside a snap and connects to an api that is serving content with a custom self signed certificate. I'd like to properly add that certificate into the store of my electron app instead of just ignoring the errors for that domain. Therefore, I added the following code into my main.ts and placed the cert file into the same directory:

```ts
app.importCertificate({
  certificate: path.join(__dirname, 'custom_certificate.p12'),
  password: "passphrase"
}, (result: number) => {
  console.log("Certificate callback result: " + result);
})
```

However, when the snap boots, I'm always getting the same error when the application tries to start:

```bash
systemd[1]: snap.electron-app.daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=133/n/a 2023-07-17T11:32:43+02:00
systemd[1]: snap.electron-app.daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've already tried moving the file into other directories and made sure it's still present in the packaged app the joined path of the certificate is exactly pointing towards it (by logging into the console in the production environment). Unfortunately, the error does not change and I can't find any documentation on that.

### Update

After putting the above codeblock into the 'on-ready'-event handler, electron starts normally again. But now, I'm getting chrome net error -807 errors (according to their documentation this signals a corrupt pkcs12 file), regardless if I put the file into that path or not.